# Using iterator to read input

Tags: c++, istream-iterator

I have the following code, which has `sin_start(cin)` function. I am not sure if there is any such function defined in C++ or if I need to define it myself. But somehow this code compiles and runs too.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Enter integers: ";
    istream_iterator<int> sin_start(cin);
}
```

Comment: The answer to your question is covered in the wiki of the tag you've used I think. Have you read that by any chance?

Comment: @cigien I couldn't find it by doing a google search. Could you paste the link?

Comment: You can just use it like any other iterator. `int x = *(sin_start++);` to read one integer from `stdin`.

Comment: But how to read till an enter is encountered?

Comment: `sin_start` is not a function. It is a variable. This line defines it. *how to read till an enter is encountered?* This is a completely different question unrelated to your main question.

Comment: @Juan `istream_iterator` will not help you detect ENTER being pressed, because it uses `operator>>` which skips whitespace between values and ENTER is treated as whitespace.

Comment: @RemyLebeau The operator skips _preceding_ whitespace, not all whitespace.

Comment: @Yun technically yes, but the end result is the same in this case.

Comment: If you click on the tag below the question, and then click "Learn more" at the top, you'll see https://stackoverflow.com/tags/istream-iterator/info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code compiles because it is valid code. It just doesn't do anything meaningful.

`sin_start` is not a function, it is a variable of type `istream_iterator<int>`, where `istream_iterator` is a template class defined in the `<iterator>` header file. It is being passed `std::cin` as a parameter to its constructor, so it knows which stream to read data from.

But the code simply exits after that variable is constructed. It is not trying to read any data. For that, try something more like this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "Enter integers: ";
    istream_iterator<int> sin_start(cin), end;
    while (sin_start != end) {
        int value = *sin_start++;
        // do something with value...
    }
}
```

That will read integers until the user cancels input on the terminal.

However, in comments, you mention that you want to read integers until the user presses <kbd>Enter</kbd> instead. In that case, you need a different approach, since `istream_iterator` uses `operator>>` internally, which skips leading whitespace on each read, and <kbd>Enter</kbd> is treated as whitespace. Try something more like this instead:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "Enter integers: ";
    string line;
    getline(cin, line);
    istringstream iss(line);
    int value;
    while (iss >> value) {
        // do something with value...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks that helped a lot. Also I wanted to know if this is the official website of c++ : https://en.cppreference.com/ or there are other online resource worth browsing?

Comment: @Juan no, it is not an official site. But it is a fairly accurate and comprehensive reference that is commonly used